# java turtle graphics and iterations

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

```
import java.awt.*;
public class TurtleGraphicsDemo2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    World worldObj = new World();
    Turtle myrtleTheTurtle = new Turtle(0, 0, worldObj); 
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 20, 50, 20);      //invokes the first drawLine() method
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, 100, 150, 50, -45);               //invokes the second drawLine() method
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, 100, 150, 100, 60);                //invokes the second drawLine() method
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 40, 100, 40);   //invokes the first drawLine() method     
  }//end of main method 
}//end of class
```

Here is the error:

TurtleGraphicsDemo2.java:19: error: cannot find symbol

```
   drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 20, 50, 20);      
   ^
```

symbol:   method drawLine(Turtle,Color,int,int,int,int)
  location: class TurtleGraphicsDemo2

My programming teacher gave us this to experiment with but I get a drawLine error, anyone know why? I do not have much experience in Java, only python. If you can fix this, or know of how I can fix it, thank you. If not, thanks for looking anyway :)

Comment: Post the error message in its entirety.

Comment: post the exact error.

Comment: I just edited in the error

Answer (score 1):

You can draw lines only inside a *Canvas*, using *Graphics2D*

```
   class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

      public MyCanvas () {
         setBackground (Color.GRAY);
         setSize(300, 300);
      }

      public void paint (Graphics g) {
         Graphics2D g2;
         g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2.drawString ("It is a custom canvas area", 70, 70);
      }
   }
```